# VB.Net Word Add-in has automatically installed itself

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I am developing an add-in for Word to add ribbon bar functions for our business.
I am developing the add-in in VB.Net using Windows Visual Studio 2017.
The machine is currently a stand-alone machine that is not connected to the main network.

My issue is that for some reason, the add-in seems to have set itself up in such a way that it appears to have already been installed on the system and loads, with the most updated code, if I just start Word normally.

Any development has been done in Debug mode and I have not been re-building the solution in release mode, and yet anything I change and then run/debug updates the code that the add-in appears to be run off when opening Word directly.

If I go through the options --> add-ins and disable the VTSO add-in it just gets enabled again. I don't seem to be able to separate a debug/development section and live code.

Edit from comments: I can accept that the VTSO needs to be installed and registered but having no separation of live code and development code is frustrating. This machine is used by others for other purposes and this includes using Word, and so any old code must be kept as comments that can set back as the working code should I need to leave part way through. I cannot leave anything partially written as any run the debug mode will set the code as live.

Comment: Did my Answer answer your question?

Comment: I will be using the Clean Solution functionality to remove the add-on from the machine before others come on to do their stuff. Thanks for the help again Cindy!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is normal behavior. When you debug, VSTO registers the add-in in the Windows Registry. This is all that's required for the Office application to find and load the add-in when it starts.

If you disable the add-in in Word, it will remain disabled until you again debug the add-in in Visual Studio.

If you share the machine and want to have the add-in under development disabled for other users:

1. Work with separate user profiles. VSTO registers its add-ins under CurrentUser, not for all users - VSTO isn't designed to register add-ins for the entire machine. OR
2. Get into the habit of using Visual Studio's Build/Clean Solution functionality when you leave the machine. That unregisters the add-in (until it runs in debug mode again).